# convert to_char(..,'MON-YYYY') into sql server

Tags: sql-server, plsql

I have the following query with plsql

```
SELECT to_char(add_months(l_max_date, l_rec.MON_INTERVAL),'MON-YYYY')
   FROM    dual
```

I  am looking to write it with sql sever

```
  select CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(DATEADD(mm, MON_INTERVAL, l_max_date)))
from  rec
```

How to write

```
to_char(..,'MON-YYYY') into sql server
```

Comment: Which database version? SQL Server 2012+ the equivalent is the `FORMAT` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    SubString(Convert(Varchar(Max), tbl.theDate,0), 1, 3) + '-' 
    + Cast(Year(tbl.theDate) As Varchar(Max))
FROM
(
    select CONVERT(VARCHAR(2),MONTH(DATEADD(mm, MON_INTERVAL, l_max_date))) as theDate
    from  rec 
) AS tbl
```

Comment: No reason to do this in SQL Server 2012+, the FORMAT command can format dates and numbers using the same formatting strings as .NET

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : Yes that is true. But can you say with 100% sertenty that the OP is using mssql 2012+?. I gave the op an answer that will work not mather of the version

Comment: Not as flexible or maintainable though. Also, it's much more verbose than eg Patrick's solution and involves unnecessary casts to `varchar(max)`, a BLOB type.

Answer (score 1):

There is no [default date format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) in SQL Server like that. You have to come up with your own.

```
SELECT datename(month, getdate())
       + '-'
       + convert(nvarchar, year(getdate()))
```

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+ you can use the [FORMAT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) function to format a value using the same formatting string you would use in .NET:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'MMM-yyyy')
```

Comment: In my opinion, this would be the best answer when using 2012. +1